# Does a "changed password" mean an old password?

Tags: passive-voice

1. [A new password should differ from the changed password by at least 4
   characters](https://www.usna.edu/PasswordPortal/password-policy.php).
2. [Once you Changed your password, you may use the changed
   password for all future logins](http://faculty.elac.edu/distanceed/docs/sis/pdf/first-time-login.pdf)(This is linked to a large PDF file).

I found the sentences above on the Internet. I think the "changed" in the first one means "old" whereas the "changed" in the second one means "new". The first sentence is strange to me. Can the "changed" mean either "new" or "old" depending on the context?

.

Comment: You can’t have a changed password unless you have an old password and a new password – that’s how I’d explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exactly right: it is ambiguous, and requires context to be clear.

Having said that, I think the meaning in 2) is more natural, and that would be how I understood "The changed password" unless the context made it clear that 1) was meant.